# How do I hide blocks in TeXnicCenter

Tags: texniccenter, block

Somehow I turned on the possibility of hiding the blocks (see the picture). I can't find the way to turn it off. Couldn't you help me?

P.S. The editor is Texniccenter.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In TeXnicCenter click on `View` and then uncheck `Fold Margin`.  Then the line with the boxed minus sign disappears as you want.

**But don't forget to first** click on all plus signs in the fold margin to be sure that there are no more unshown lines.  See the following image:

[image: With hidden lines]

After clicking on the plus sign you have (see more lines, no plus sign):

[image: no hidden lines]

And now you can delete the fold margin:

[image: no fold margin]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did the same before but it seemed to make no effect. But all that I needed is to close and run again the Texniccenter so now it works. Thank you :-)